# Location context is lost between "jobs" and "company pages" when coming from Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers), when coming from Stack Overflow:

[image: Careers from Stack Overflow]

When switching from "jobs" to "company pages":

[image: Careers search results by location]

The **location** context is lost:

[image: Location context lost]

See the [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) on the images.

Comment: I'll forward this over to the devs and see what they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be resolved, let me know if any issues.

Comment: Thank you, I do not see any issue anymore.