# Search context unexpected change when switching from "x jobs" to "x company pages"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

On (for example) http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/linux when one clicks on the `x company pages` tab:

1) The amount of Linux jobs changes to what looks like all jobs currently listed on careers.stackoverflow.com
-and-
2) The previously stated "company pages" quantity, which I presume is supposed to be companies with listed Linux jobs, changes to what looks like all companies, with any currently listed jobs on careers.stackoverflow.com

Please see below *before*:

[image: Before clicking "647 company pages"]

... and *after*, screenshots.

[image: After clicking "647 company pages"]

Comment: Well, easy to see the URL lost any trace of linux so it's indeed just a list of all jobs/company pages. :(

Comment: Yeah, realised that, but as noted this isn't what I expected (Why not just display the 4111 company pages on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/linux then), and post-submitting-question looking through related q's, what others seemingly did either - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184453/location-context-is-lost-between-jobs-and-company-pages-when-coming-from-sta?rq=1. This one also, but seemingly likely not the same root issue http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193214/location-context-changes-country-between-jobs-and-company-pages?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, those are similar bugs, but not the same to the one you report. Developer will have to write new code/fix existing code to fix it.

Comment: You are correct. I'll get someone to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Is that a cursor, or did some Roman blow a snot rocket on your screen?

Comment: @Won't You obviously had your head stuck in the sand for the 15 odd years of great SciFi ;) - http://www.maxstyles.com/download.php?view.44

Comment: @Juice fixed now, can be changed to [meta-tag:status-completed] :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be better now. Try it again?

Comment: It's showing "Did you mean lines?" which is quite odd since it should be a tag search, not free form search. Can the suggested correction be removed in this case?

Comment: I have only tried my example tag search again, but it does appear to now be working as I expected. Thanks.